# wordpress categories narrow down results

Tags: customization, categories

I was wondering if there is such a functionality in the category system of wordpress that would allow me to narrow down results by category order.

So the category structure is this
there are brand categories

```
/category/brand-1/
/category/brand-2/
```

etc

there are also categories like

```
cars
appliances
components
```

What I try to achieve is this display all products that have brand-1 as a category and appliances as a category too.

```
/category/brand-1/appliances/
```

in wordpress shows products of brand-1 + appliances but also of brand-2 which happens to have products attached to appliances as a category.

is there any possibility to filter out all these other products so that I leave exclusively products of brand-1 AND appliances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you be more specific? there's a few ways to interpret what you've said depending on wether your use of AND/exclusively is meant using boolean logic or common conversational logic. E.g. do you mean you want to list posts that have both those categories and only posts that have both at the same time? Excluding posts that only have one or the other but not both? Have you attempted the URLs you've tried? You can usually append additional query parameters to the end of a URL and it will incorporate them, but this falls apart if the templates start with a `WP_Query` or `query_posts` override

Comment: Hi. So if brand 1 has 10 products
and 3 of those products also are attached to appliances category
then if I access /brand-1/appliances
only 3 products which have appliances and brand-1 must show. The rest of brand-1 (which don't have appliances cat attached to them should be left out).
I don't know if I am explaining correctly

Comment: that makes more sense, thanks for confirming, did you try adding the URL parameters like I mentioned? All of the query parameters that are listed for `WP_Query` also work in the URL too, e.g. you can turn your category into a search by adding `?s=term` to the end of the URL and it will search just that category, likewise all the category/tag parameters should work too. I think the technical term for what you want is an intersection, but I also think most people writing about it wouldn't know to call it that either

Comment: Can it be accesed via the default category permalink structure? Or i need to overwrite the category loop/function

Comment: it's literally opening the address bar in your browser and adding the parameters, it's not something that requires PHP code, e.g. i can load posts that have 2 tags in common on my site with `/?tag=gutenberg+php`. This is default standard WP behaviour, overwriting the category loop/function would break this

Comment: problem is i dont wand to use ?tag= and pluses

Comment: which is why I left it as a comment, figuring out that what I mentioned is possible is a critical part necessary to figure out how to do `/category/first/second/`. Answering the question without knowing this would be 1000x more difficult. Infact knowing that `/?tag=gutenberg+php` works _heavily_ implies a solution that involves no URL parameters ( hint: `+` ). Note that the specific URL format `/category/a/b/` has a major problem in that by default this would match child terms, e.g. where b is a child term of a, and you may get a canonical redirect, and conflicting rewrite rules.

Comment: I've left an answer, but if you read it you should see that figuring out how to do it with raw URL parameters is a crucial part of getting a pretty URL working. If you ignore the raw URL version of the answer it is impossible to figure out the pretty permalink options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, what you literally want is directly in conflict with a permalink pattern that already exists.

Namely, that if I have a term A, with a child B, B's permalink would be:

```
/category/A/B
```

But if you wrote this expecting an intersection of C and B like this it would not work, it would interpret this as the archive for B, and potentially redirect:

```
category/C/B
```

For these reasons, what you *literally* asked for is not possible, and not desirable.

### Showing Posts that have both terms via a URL *without* writing extra code

These methods work out of the box, assuming your template uses a standard main post loop, and does not use `WP_Query`/`get_posts`/`query_posts` or a page builder to display the category posts:

- `/category/A+B/`
- `?category_name=A+B`

This works on all WordPress installs, and can even be appended to other WordPress archives to filter them.

Not only that, but because they're URL parameters, they can be set up with form inputs and `method="GET"` to set up a filtering system super easily.

### Creating New URLs

You could use rewrite rules, and do this with some kind of `comparison` type slug to avoid the clashes I mentioned earlier. e.g. `/combine/categories/A/B`.

***Note that doing this will have the same SEO properties as using URL parameters, but with less flexibility, and the added cost of building it. The only benefit to this is that the URL will be prettier.***

#### An Example That *Almost* Works When Copy Pasted

```php
function custom_rewrite_rule() : void {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^combine/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]+$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0 );
```

*In theory,* after flushing permalinks by visiting the permalinks page, this would allow URLs such as `/combine/A/B/` to view posts that have both A and B.

Note that if you are using a category template that lists the main posts using a secondary query or page builder then this too will not work. The rewrite rules system feeds the main posts query, not secondary queries made with `new WP_Query`/etc

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was struggling with.

Comment: note that you don't have to make a single rewrite rule do everything, you can have multiple rules that match different situations, as long you put them in the right order, with the most specific first and the most generic last

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to implement paginatiom with this one?

Comment: you should ask a new question